# Incorrect syntax near '-' 2

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my project in C# and I really can't find the problem...

The debug says:

> Incorrect syntax near '-'

This is the problematic code:

```
 if (!MyAdoHelperCsharp.IsExist("DB.mdf", sql))
 {       
    insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Tables (TableNum,SitNum,Position,Busy,Sunday-7:00,Sunday-8:00,Sunday-9:00,Sunday-10:00,Sunday-11:00,Sunday-12:00,Sunday-13:00,Sunday-14:00,Sunday-15:00,Sunday-16:00,Sunday-17:00,Sunday-18:00,Sunday-19:00,Sunday-20:00,Sunday-21:00,Sunday-22:00,Monday-7:00,Monday-8:00,Monday-9:00,Monday-10:00,Monday-11:00,Monday-12:00,Monday-13:00,Monday-14:00,Monday-15:00,Monday-16:00,Monday-17:00,Monday-18:00,Monday-19:00,Monday-20:00,Monday-21:00,Monday-22:00,Tuesday-7:00,Tuesday-8:00,Tuesday-9:00,Tuesday-10:00,Tuesday-11:00,Tuesday-12:00,Tuesday-13:00,Tuesday-14:00,Tuesday-15:00,Tuesday-16:00,Tuesday-17:00,Tuesday-18:00,Tuesday-19:00,Tuesday-20:00,Tuesday-21:00,Tuesday-22:00,Wednesday-7:00,Wednesday-8:00,Wednesday-9:00,Wednesday-10:00,Wednesday-11:00,Wednesday-12:00,Wednesday-13:00,Wednesday-14:00,Wednesday-15:00,Wednesday-16:00,Wednesday-17:00,Wednesday-18:00,Wednesday-19:00,Wednesday-20:00,Wednesday-21:00,Wednesday-22:00,Thursday-7:00,Thursday-8:00,Thursday-9:00,Thursday-10:00,Thursday-11:00,Thursday-12:00,Thursday-13:00,Thursday-14:00,Thursday-15:00,Thursday-16:00,Thursday-17:00,Thursday-18:00,Thursday-19:00,Thursday-20:00,Thursday-21:00,Thursday-22:00,Friday-7:00,Friday-8:00,Friday-9:00,Friday-10:00,Friday-11:00,Friday-12:00,Friday-13:00,Friday-14:00) VALUES ('";
    insertQuery += tablenum + "','" + SitNum + "','" + position + "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "','" + false+ "')";
    MessageBox.Show(insertQuery);
    MyAdoHelperCsharp.DoQuery("DB.mdf", insertQuery);
}
```

Thank you very much! And sorry for the long code :)

Comment: Try wrapping `Sunday-7:00` and other similar columns with `[` and `]` like this: `[Sunday-7:00]`.

Comment: The name of your column is 'Sunday-7:00'?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your column names are using operators, which SQL will not understand correctly and think are actually trying to do calculations, which in this case is `Sunday - 1:00`, which obviously does not end up giving an answer and is in fact an error altogether. That is what causes the error

> Incorrect syntax near '-'

To fix this, any fields which contain operators, reserved keywords or any other invalid characters, for example spaces, you need to contain them in square brackets so that SQL **knows** it is a field name instead of guessing about it and then getting it wrong, for example

```
insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Tables (TableNum, SitNum, Position,Busy, [Sunday-7:00], [Sunday-8:00],...)"
```

It may also be worth putting line breaks into your code every now and again as this is **very unreadable** this helps to read long strings such as SQL statements like so

```
insertQuery = "INSERT INTO Tables 
(TableNum,SitNum,Position,Busy,
[Sunday-7:00],[Sunday-8:00],...)";
```